# Removal of old kernels without deleting all

Tags: kernel

I am looking for a way to remove all the old kernels but keep 1 just in case.

```
dpkg --list | grep linux-image | awk '{ print $2 }' | sort -V | sed -n '/'`uname -r`'/q;p' | xargs sudo apt-get -y purge
```

This command has worked fairly well but removes all old kernels. Is it possible to leave a spare kernel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Install `byobu` utility:

```
sudo apt install byobu
```

To remove all of old kernels except two last run:

```
sudo purge-old-kernels -qy --keep 2
```